# Determine Type of PL/SQL Exception

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleexception

In an OTHERS exception block I'd like to display the type of exception.

```
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( -- I want to display the type of exception here -- ); 
END;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the type of the exception"? What would you expect to be printed if you got a TOO_MANY_ROWS exception?

Comment: try this DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM)

Comment: Similar to @Aramillo, the documentation on invoking `SQLCODE` (similar function to `SQLERRM`) has an example that provides error code and message for `WHEN OTHERS`. Here it is http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqlcode_function.htm.

Comment: By the way, you might find this valuable, http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2012/05/pokemon-and-when-others.html.

Comment: I really get uncomfortable when I see developers using `WHEN OTHERS` without thinking what to do with the exception. I just wrote an answer in brief, rather as pithy as possible. But, this bad practice has brought attention on a wide range over the web.

Comment: @Patrick, Good that you posted Tom's link. I just jotted down the important points out of Tom's suggestion from that huge thread here http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/05/02/when-others-then-null-a-bug/ I hope Thomas Kyte won't mind being my colleague at work place ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer a robust exception block rather than a trivial `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN` without any specific purpose. Always remember, you catch exception and then DO something about it. Else, you need to RE-RAISE it to give the handle back to the caller.

In your exception block, add the following :

`DBMS_UTILITY. FORMAT_ERROR_STACK;
DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE`

This will give you the error stack and the backtrace procedure will let you know the exactnline number of error. Since EXCEPTION takes the handle from the caller, thus the caller never comes to know about the error raised. Include `RAISE` statement to re-raise the error and give it back to the caller. Better have an error logging table to have the errors logged for future research.

And regarding when others, please read my article, http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/05/02/when-others-then-null-a-bug/

Comment: Another suggestion, **3rd party client tools** are not as efficient as **SQL*Plus** when it comes to replicate OP's issue. I seriously prefer SQL*Plus to believe an issue, and it has had always helped me in rectifying them.